# Qt wheelEvent not called when moving mouse

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following class, which inherits QGraphicsView :

```
class CurveGraphicView : public QGraphicsView {
Q_OBJECT

protected:
    virtual void resizeEvent( QResizeEvent* event ) override;
    virtual void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* event) override;
};
```

I have to following code inside wheelEvent :

```
void CurveGraphicView::wheelEvent( QWheelEvent* event ) {

    float zoomInFactor = 1.25;

    float zoomOutFactor = 1 / zoomInFactor;
    float zoomFactor = zoomOutFactor;

    if(event->angleDelta().y() > 0){
        zoomFactor = zoomInFactor;
    }

    scale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor);
}
```

As so can see, I'm using wheel event to zoom in/out inside the view.

It works well, except that this function is not called when I'm moving the mouse and using mouse wheel at the same time.

The following piece of code works :

```
int main( int argv, char** args) {

    QApplication qtApp(argv, args);

    CurveGraphicView view;
    view.show();

    return qtApp.exec();
}
```

After a few research, I think finally isolated the problem, but I still didn't resolve it :

CurveGraphicView parent Widget also contains a QOpenGLWidget. When I remove this QOpenGLWidget, the issue doesn't appear anymore :

```
class Curve2DOpenGLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Core {
Q_OBJECT    
public:

    Curve2DOpenGLWidget( QWidget* parent = nullptr,
                         const QString& xLabel = "x",
                         const QString& yLabel = "y",
                         const QString& zLabel = "z" );
    ~Curve2DOpenGLWidget();

    void CheckGLError();

    void initializeGL() override;
    void resizeGL(int width, int height) override;

    //Function mixing QPainter Drawings and Native OpenGL calls
    void paintGL() override;

    //Native OpenGL calls
    void NativePaintGL();

protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) override;
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;
    void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event) override;
};
```

Any idea ?

**EDIT :**

I reposted this topic in a clearer way :
[Qt QOpenGLWidget wheelEvent strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673477/qt-qopenglwidget-wheelevent-strange-behaviour)

Comment: What do you mean by "moving the mouse while scrolling" exactly?

Comment: I move the mouse without clicking, and I roll mouse wheel

Comment: The posted code works fine for me.  Can you provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I just edit my issue :)