# Qt: Sometimes wheelEvent() is not called immediately when rotating the mouse wheel

Tags: linux, qt

I use Qt's `wheelEvent` to implement scrolling in a custom widget. Normally, this works fine.

However, when dragging the mouse and scrolling with the mouse wheel at the same time, it sometimes happens that rotating the mouse wheel by one step does not do anything at first (no `wheelEvent` is received). This might even randomly happen a few times successively. The next time the application does receive a `wheelEvent`, it comes with an accumulated `event->angleDelta()` of all previous events that were not reported separately. Apparently the events are buffered together in this case. Note that the `wheelEvent` may happen a long time after the initial mouse wheel rotation(s) in this case: it only happens once the wheel is rotated again.

This is an issue, since it means that my widget sometimes does not properly react to scrolling. Is there any way to avoid this kind of buffering and receive all wheel events immediately instead?

Notably this behavior is only well reproducible if at the same time dragging the mouse within the widget, which performs some non-trivial actions as a result. So I suspect it might happen if the event loop seems busy. But it certainly isn't busy enough to be unable to handle each `wheelEvent`. So I would like to disable this buffering.

I observe this on Linux with Qt 5.12.0. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question here since I found the answer after writing it (but was unable to google it before).

The same problem has been reported here (with a somewhat non-descriptive title): [Qt QOpenGLWidget wheelEvent strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673477/qt-qopenglwidget-wheelevent-strange-behaviour)

For me, setting `Qt::AA_CompressHighFrequencyEvents` (see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ApplicationAttribute-enum) to false seems to have fixed the issue, as posted by [@gatis paeglis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7362458/gatis-paeglis) as an answer to that question.

Comment: That an isolated first event without subsequent events gets hold back forever seems like a bug in the compression algorithm...

Comment: This doesn't fix the same problem for me in Qt 6.4.